# Application to remotelly control rutorrent

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I have ruTorrent installed on a server. When I want to add torrents to it, I need to access it's WebUI. I don't find it very comfortable, so my question is: Is there any way (any application that I can install on Windows) so I can remotely control ruTorrent on the server side, from my desktop, with the experience of a local torrent client?

Comment: What features are you looking for exactly? Some people install BTSync to sync .torrent files to a watched folder on the Linux server. This way, torrents are automatically loaded into rTorrent. Alternatively, you can rent a Windows server, and run µTorrent on there with the WebUI.